# How to check in C++ that console is filled up?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, console

I am writing a program that searches for files in the filesystem, and outputs all pathes into the console. 
So, these might be too big, and I need to clean up the screen when it's full. How to check it?

Comment: Why do you need to _cleanup the screen_? If you throw away the information anyway, why not just let it scroll out with the screen buffer?

Comment: If the user wants to have paging, let the user pipe it to `more` or `less` themselves. That's the standard way to handle these things.

Answer (score 1):

With pure C++, this is not possible. C++ has no notion of a "console", it just has a very abstract notion of "text output".

A typical Linux solution would be to rely on pipes and the [`less`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/less) command. So just let your program write everything to standard output. A user who wants to view everything in the console can then invoke it like this:

```
./my_program | less
```